# How get header of the table fixed ?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How get header of the table fixed while the table data is scrolling down  via jquery !
  the height of the table fixed

```
<html>
 <body>
  <style type="text/css">
   <table class="fx">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>Email ID</th>
       <th>Time Taken to complete game (secs)</th>
       <th>Email ID</th><th>Time Taken to complete game (secs)</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
 <table class="data">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>asd@gmail.com</td>
    <td>449</td>
    <td>asd@gmail.com</td>
    <td>449</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
    <td>sad@gmail.com</td>
    <td>449</td><td>asd@gmail.com</td>
    <td>449</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <tr>
     <td>as@gmail.com</td>
     <td>449</td>
     <td>asd@gmail.com</td>
     <td>449</td>
    </tr>
     <tr> 
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

    table tbody
    {
       display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
          }
      table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    table tr{
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    table tr:nth-child(odd){

        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table tr:nth-child(even){

        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    table tr td{
        padding:10px;
        width: 200px; 
         max-width: 200px;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color:#5d8d5d;
    }
    .fx{
         position: fixed;
      top: 0;

      left: 0;
      }

      .fx tr th {
        padding:10px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        width: 200px;
        color:#6d4d9d;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .data{
      margin-top: 70px;
    }

    div{
      position: relative;

    }
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    </style>
    <div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

How get header of the table fixed while the table data is scrolling down  via jquery !
  the height of the table need urgently

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque

Comment: *need urgently smells bad*, it shows your boss is going to smack you up.. anyways, your table seems to have a fixed `width` so you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17828082/1542290 .. by the way that's **PURE CSS**

Comment: haha right boss is going to kick my ass if nt done :)

Comment: yea see.. there you go...

Comment: Why your `table` markup is within the `style` tag? Also, there's an extra `</div>` there.

Answer (score 1):

See this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Gv9Nb/17/)

**OR**

Could you please try this...

CSS Style :

```
<style>
        table tbody
    {
        display: block;
        height: 262px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    table
    {
        table-layout: fixed;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    table tr
    {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    table tr:nth-child(odd)
    {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table tr:nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    table tr td
    {
        padding: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: #5d8d5d;
    }
    .fx
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
       min-width:850px;
       width:850px;
    }

    .fx tr th
    {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        width: 175px;
        min-width: 175px;
        color: #6d4d9d;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .data
    {
        margin-top: 0px;
        min-width:850px;
        width:850px;
        left: 0;
    }
    .data tr th
    {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 175px;
        min-width: 175px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    *
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML :

```
<table class="fx">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Email ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Time Taken to complete game (secs)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Time Taken to complete game (secs)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="data" style="valign: top; overflow: auto; min-width:850px; height: 100px; margin-top: 60px;
        padding-top: 0px">
        <table class="data">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        asd@gmail.com
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        449
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        asd@gmail.com
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        449
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            sad@gmail.com
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            449
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            asd@gmail.com
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            449
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                as@gmail.com
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                449
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                asd@gmail.com
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                449
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @user3011961 Have you got the chance to check it?

Comment: Its not working as expected sorry, but thanks actually you can the column lines of the td are not properly aligned to the header lines they are moving a apart !

Comment: @user3011961 But function which you need (stick header and just move records) is fulfill or not? if it is fulfill then I can align record's lines with header columns line.

Comment: yeah partially but i want aligned col lines , thanx in advance

Comment: the straight lines of td section is moving away from th section line(borders)

Comment: @user3011961 You are wasting my time. I think you need to learn HTML and CSS from basic. because after this much help you can't do anything from your side.

Comment: First of all my friend if you want points here then give correct solutions second thing is no body ask to to come here and help so don't give idiotic excuses !

Comment: @user3011961 I don't want points. We are here to improve my knowledge but your requirement are very in each communication. You need scrollable item with sticky header. I have give you that, but now your requirement is changed. :)

Comment: @user3011961 You have to put some efforts from your side also.

Comment: Thanks for the gentle reply , and sorry if question varied may be you are right , Thx bydway for your time !

Comment: @user3011961 I do not want to waste more my and your time also.