# shrinking tr width when it get position fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have a table of data which cols is determined automatically with its data.

but I need to fix first row as header title "for scrolling it remains fix at the top". when I give it `position:fixed` , header row`s width shrinks comparing to others!!!

first pic before setting `position:fixed` :
[image]
after setting `position:fixed`:
[image]

I can't change my structure code, because there are too many similar tables !!!!  Only css or javascript can be used.

my code :

```
     <table class="list_row_container">
             <tr class="list_row_title">
               <td width="30px" align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="keyCheckbox" onclick="updateCheckboxes(this.checked)"></td>
               <td>
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&date=asc">تاریخ ثبت</a>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&karbariId=desc">نوع کاربری   </a>
               </td>
                                <td>  
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&addressMantaghe=desc">آدرس منطقه </a>
              </td>

              <td>
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&zirBana=desc">زیر بنا </a>
              </td>   
              <td>
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&tabaghe=desc">طبقه</a>
              </td>
              <td> 
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&tedadeOtagh=desc">اتاق </a>
              </td>
              <td> 
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&omreBana=desc">عمر </a>
              </td>                                     
              <td>           
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&ejare=desc">اجاره</a>
             </td>                                            
             <td>
                   <a href="index.php?file=file&operation=list&priceTotal=desc">ودیعه </a>
             </td>      
             <td>&nbsp; مشاهده</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="list_row_even" id="row492314"    >
             <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="info[rowIds][492314]"></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">1394/02/29</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">موقعيت اداري                          </span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">.بلوار فردوس غرب  پروانه شمالي  خ شقايق غربي  پ 8</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">100</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">2</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">2</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">1</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext"> -</span></td>
             <td class="list_field_container"><span class"list_field_normaltext">660,000,000</span></td>
             <td>
               <a id="viewmbt-492314"  style="cursor: pointer;"  title="مشاهده مشاور"><img  src="../images/search.png" alt="مشاهده" /></a>
               <a id="viewmbt2-492314"  style="cursor: pointer;"   title="مشاهده مشتری"><img  src="../images/groupIcon.png" alt="مشاهده" /></a>
             </td>
         </tr>
....
```

css style :

```
    .list_container
{
   width:100%; border:1px solid #395bc2;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
min-height:100px;
display:table;

}
.list_header
{
   width:98%; padding:1%; height:10px;
background: #c9e3fd; /* Old browsers */

-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
color:#000099;
line-height:10px;
font-size: 18px;
}
.list_footer_container
{
    background-color: #ffcc99;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list_has_no_row
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
}
.list_row_container img
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
.fixed-header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.list_row_container
{
    border-top: 1px silver navy;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
}
.list_row_title
{
    background-color: #ffcc99;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000099;
}
.list_row_title td{padding: 10px;}

.list_row_even
{
    background-color: #ffffff;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
}
.list_row_even:hover
{
     background-color: #ffcc99;       
}
.list_row_odd
{
    background-color: #c9e3fc;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
}
.list_row_odd:hover{
     background-color: #ffcc99;       
}
.list_field_container
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.list_row_title {
  background-color: #9c42a0;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Could you update your code in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Add your `CSS` styles.

Comment: check related questions - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling) , [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque), [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827908/how-to-make-fixed-header-table-inside-scrollable-div)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/drp6ogtq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            /// get the td`s width automatically and set inline style width for all tds 
            $(".list_row_title td").each(function(index){
                var index2 = index;
                $(this).width(function(index2){
                    return $(".list_row_container td").eq(index).width();
                });
            });
            $(".list_row_even td").each(function(index){
                var index2 = index;
                $(this).width(function(index2){
                    return $(".list_row_container td").eq(index).width();
                });
            });
            ///if scroll make fix header tr
            var $window = $(window);

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (scroll >= 250) {

                    $(".list_row_title").addClass('fixed_table_header');
                }
                else {

                    $(".list_row_title").removeClass('fixed_table_header');
                }
            });
        });
```

style :

```
.fixed_table_header
{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
```