# How to make html table scrollable with fixed headers?

Tags: jquery

I have table with lots of rows. I want to make it vertically scrollable but with fixed headers.

Comment: Have you tried Any thing?

Comment: Yes. i put that table inside this div <div style="height:300px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">. But whole table got scrollable along with header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433833/fix-table-header-at-top-of-scrollable-div/31434590#31434590

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to make the elements of the table scollable.

Say you have table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='scrollable'>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Write CSS as below:

```
.scrollable{ 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```