# How to add table pagination into exixting table in html

Tags: pagination

currently i want to do table pagination example that found in http://hazaa.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-html-table-with-frozen-headers-and-columns/. I managed to come out the table that shown in the example but don't know how to do the table pagination.Anyone can guide me on this? TQ.

Comment: That page is from 2009, though. An age before HTML5 and decent uniformity in browsers...

Comment: is it? Then where i can look for same example like that?

Comment: If all you want are fixed headers on a scrolling table... [you could try this nice site called StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17827908/395685) ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "pagination" though. There doesn't seem to be anything like that on that page you linked.

Comment: what i mean is i already create the table like the example and now i want to add a pagination on the table to avoid long table show in the page

Comment: So your linked example actually has nothing to do with what you really want to do. Splitting up table data into multiple pages is generally the sort of thing that's handled on the server side in web applications, through ajax calls. In pure HTML, the only conceivable way I could see is a rather elaborate Javascript program called from the pagination links that changes all the cell data. You didn't even tag your question with "javascript".